# Программа не проходит тесты

Tags: javascript, node.js

Стоит задача реализовать функцию, через которую можно управлять телефонной книгой.

Для управления телефонной книгой нужно реализовать три команды:

- ADD — добавляет контакт
- SHOW —возвращает содержимое телефонной книг
- REMOVE_PHONE — удаляет номер

Команда **ADD**
Добавляет контакт в телефонную книгу со списком телефонов. Телефоны перечисляются через запятую. Если такой контакт существует, то команда пополняет список телефонов контакта
Пример команды ADD: *ADD Ivan 555-10-01,555-10-03*.

Команда **REMOVE_PHONE**
Удаляет телефон из телефонной книги. Если телефон успешно удалён, то функция должна вернуть true. Если такого телефона в телефонной книге не существует, то возвращается false.

Команда **SHOW**
Возвращает массив контактов с их телефонами. Массив содержит строчки вида: "Имя: Телефон1, Телефон2". Массив должен быть отсортирован по имени контакта. Телефоны идут в порядке добавления их в телефонную книгу. Контакт с пустым списком телефонов не должен возвращаться.

Я очень слаб в js,поэтому написал (говно)код,который проходит 3 теста из 13(они закрытые). Если выполнять код на локальной машине,то все соответствует образцу. Пожалуйста,подскажите, где программа ведет себя или может вести себя неправильно,уже все перерыл. Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь. Спасибо.
P.s - написал комментарии скорее для себя, что бы было понимание происходящего. Если они тупые и очевидные,прошу прощения.

```
var phoneBook = {}; // используем структуру объекта,где свойство - имя, значение - массив номеров,принадлежащих этому имени.

/**
 * @param {String} command
 * @returns {*} - результат зависит от команды
 */
module.exports = function  (command) {  //для того,что бы вызывать из другого файла
    
 
    commands  = command.split(' '); 
    indef = commands[0]; //первый элемент в строке - команда
    

    if(indef == 'ADD'){
        name = commands[1]; //2 - имя
        numbers = commands[2].split(','); //3 - строка с номерами через запятую,которую приводим к массиву 
        
        if(!phoneBook.hasOwnProperty(name)){ //если такого имени нету в объекте
            phoneBook[name] = numbers;  //добавляем его и соотносим с массивом номеров
        }
        else {  //если имя есть
            
            for(i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
                
                phoneBook[name].push(numbers[i]); //добавляем в уже существующий массив номера
                
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    
    else if(indef == 'REMOVE_PHONE') {
        numb_remove = commands[1];
        for(name in phoneBook){     //перебираем имена
            if(phoneBook[name].includes(numb_remove)){ //перебираем номера и если есть
                x = phoneBook[name].indexOf(numb_remove); //получаем его индекс
                phoneBook[name].splice(x,1);//удаляем из объекта
                return true;
            }
         
        }
        return false;
        
    
    }
    
    
    
    else if(indef = 'SHOW'){
        var names = Object.keys(phoneBook).sort(); //получаем список имен и сортируем его
        
        var book = ['\n'];                        //создаем массив строк, который будет выводится на экран
        
        for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
            book.push(names[i] + ': ' + phoneBook[names[i]].join(',') + '\n'); //задание структуры name1: phone1,phone2
                                                                                                  // name2: phone1,phone2
        }
        if(book.length > 0){
            return book;
        }
         
            
    }
    
    
};
```

Comment: Одна из ошибок: `else if (indef = 'SHOW') {` — присваивание вместо сравнения. Исправьте и посмотрите, сколько тестов будет пройдено.

Comment: Это тоже нужно проверить: в условии SHOW  вовзращает «"Имя: Телефон1, Телефон2"» (с пробелом после запятой), а в коде вы разделяете вывод телефонов запятой без пробела.

Comment: Далее: в коде вы добавляете строчку для имени, не проверяя, есть ли у имени список телефонов, а в условии строчка не должна добавляться, если телефонов нет.

Comment: Ну и есть несколько моментов, которые по условию вроде не оговорены, не не знаю, проверяются ли они в тестах. Что должно происходить, если задана неправильная команда (не из списка допустимых) или в формате команды ошибка (например, телефоны разделены запятой с пробелом — это ошибка или допустимый вариант, который нужно учесть). Что нужно вернуть, если список пустой. Сейчас вы в любом случае возвращаете массив с телефонами или с одним переводом строки (то есть `if(book.length > 0)` всегда верно).

Comment: Ну и для большей надёжности: старайтесь всегда объявлять переменные при помощи `const` или `let`. Сейчас вы создаёте кучу глобальные переменных. Вроде в данном коде это не проблема, если я ничего не пропустил, но это рано или поздно может иметь плохие и трудно уловимые последствия.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное. Забыл написать,что корректность получаемых данных проверять не нужно(по условию).Сейчас попытаюсь исправить все ошибки и отпишусь.

Comment: Да, элемент с единственным переводом строки в массиве тоже может нарушать требования тестов.

Comment: Да, и непонятно, должен ли быть перевод строки в конце каждой строки с телефонами. Вы же должны возвращать массив записей, про форматирование ничего не говорится. Попробуйте возвращать массив без первого элемента с переводом строки (т.е. создавайте `book` как пустой массив) и не добавлять переводы после строчек с телефонами.

Comment: Действительно,без '\n' Прошло 11 из 13 тестов. Почти победа)

Comment: Если вы будете создавать `book` как пустой массив, тогда при пустой адресной книге или книге только с именами без телефонов ваша программа в теперешнем виде будет возвращать `undefined`. По условиям не ясно, что она должна возвращать в этом случае. Возможно, пустой массив будет более логичным значением?

Comment: Да,открылись тесты и если в программе остались только имена без телефонов,то должен возвращаться пустой массив. Переписал кусок кода с "ADD", что бы пустые имена не просто не добавлялись в объект : `if(indef == 'ADD'){
  name = commands[1]; 
  numbers = commands[2].split(','); 
  if(numbers.length == 0){
   return;
  }
  if(!phoneBook.hasOwnProperty(name)){ 
   phoneBook[name] = numbers;  
  }
  else { //если имя есть
   
   for(i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    
    phoneBook[name].push(numbers[i]); 
    
   }
  } 
 }`

Comment: Ещё один момент. Что делать, если добавляется номер, который уже есть в списке для имени? Сейчас он дублируется. Возможно, тесты требуют, чтобы номера не дублировались? Тогда нужно добавить проверку и отфильтровать номера, которые уже есть в книге для данного имени.

Comment: После выполнения 75 процентов тестов,открылись передаваемые команды. Ошибка в том,что как вы верно заметили,при отсутствии номером у имени,программа не должна его возвращать.Сейчас немного отвлекусь и думаю,что чуть попозже уже добью последние два теста. Без вас бы не справился,спасибо вам большущее. Ваш код увидел,буду разбирать,пока он мне, к сожалению,мало понятен. Еще раз спасибо!!

Comment: Там просто могут встретиться какие-то плюшки, относительно недавно добавленные в язык. Они просто могут чуть сокращать, упрощать код, но логику вашу я по сути не менял. Если будут вопросы, задавайте в комментариях к ответу. Ну, или если сами справитесь с тестами, не отвлекайтесь на это)

Answer (score 1):

Постарался суммировать всё, что заметил в комментариях. Сравните на всякий случай. На детали форматирования можете не обращать внимания, я рихтовал код, чтобы мой линтер выдавал меньше ошибок.

```js
'use strict';

const phoneBook = Object.create(null);

function main(command) {
  const commands  = command.split(' ');
  const [indef] = commands;

  if (indef === 'ADD') {
    const [, name] = commands;
    const numbers = commands[2].split(',');

    if (phoneBook[name] === undefined) {
      phoneBook[name] = numbers;
    } else {
      phoneBook[name].push(...numbers);
    }
  } else if (indef === 'REMOVE_PHONE') {
    const [, numb_remove] = commands;
    for (const name of Object.keys(phoneBook)) {
      if (phoneBook[name].includes(numb_remove)) {
        const x = phoneBook[name].indexOf(numb_remove);
        phoneBook[name].splice(x, 1);
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  } else if (indef === 'SHOW') {
    const names = Object.keys(phoneBook).sort();
    const book = [];

    for (const name of names) {
      if (phoneBook[name].length > 0) {
        book.push(`${name}: ${phoneBook[name].join(',')}`);
      }
    }
    return book;
  }
}

console.log(main('SHOW'));
console.log(main('ADD A 555'));
console.log(main('ADD A 777'));
console.log(main('SHOW'));
console.log(main('ADD B 111,222'));
console.log(main('SHOW'));
console.log(main('REMOVE_PHONE 555'));
console.log(main('REMOVE_PHONE 222'));
console.log(main('REMOVE_PHONE 999'));
console.log(main('SHOW'));
console.log(main('REMOVE_PHONE 111'));
console.log(main('SHOW'));
console.log(main('ADD B 111'));
console.log(main('SHOW'));
```